# Unity: GUI button with event trigger as virtual control pad on Android phone

Tags: user-interface, button, unity-game-engine, touch, eventtrigger

Let's say I have two GUI buttons with EventTrigger as virtual key. The expectation is whenever a button is pressed, the camera will rotate until the button is released.

At the beginning, I used the pointer Down and pointer up function. It works, but it extremely sensitive, the camera rotation didn't stop at the moment when I release my finger. I've solved this problem by using drag function (whenever dragging is detected, the camera stop rotating something like that).

However, there is still a bug that I couldn't solve, that is if I swipe the button instead of touch&release, the button doesn't release. eventually the camera just keep rotating until I touch the button again. I've tried all the event trigger function such as pointer exist, end drag etc. 
I just want the touch input works as perfectly as the keyboard input.

This problem doesn't shown when I debugging on unity remote, only when I build it on my phone. So is that hardware issue? (I'm using mi3)

Thanks for having time to read my broken English.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry that I've asked a stupid question, since I'm still kind of beginner. The problem is somehow it didn't update when I installed it in my phone. It actually works fine.